# flextable freeze and/or lock columns and header

Tags: gwt, expression, locked, flextable

There are a ton of freeze/lock column solutions on this site but as far as I can tell none of them give me the answer I need.  I'm using GWT 2.4 and a FlexTable and without creating two tables I would like to be able to freeze the header row so it is always visible during vertical scrolling and to be able to freeze left column(s) so they are always visible during horizontal scrolling.  This worked with GWT 1.7 using css expressions (code written a while ago), however GWT decided to remove support for css expressions and I'm at a loss as to how replace them to get the functionality back.

**css expression used for headers:** top: expression(parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop-2);

**css expression used for locked column:** left: expression(parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollLeft-2);

I've seen solutions where you use two tables however I really need a one table solution and I just don't know enough javascript or jquery to convert those css expressions to something that works.

Thanks for your time.